# Session value is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is an ASP.NET MVC project. I'm trying to retrieve value from a session and it always returns null.

The `SaveToSession` & `GetFromSession` methods are in a separate helper class.
When the submit button is clicked, it makes a call to the controller method and in turn to the helper method to save data in session.

Another anchor tag click (which has the controller path) will hit the same controller which calls the helper method to fetch the data from session. This is where the data is null always.

These are the methods in my helper class

```
public static void SaveDataInSession(string sessionName, IEnumerable<Item> lstData)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionName] = lstData;            
}

public static void GetDataFromSession(string sessionName, out IEnumerable<Item> lstData)
{
    lstData = null;

    var test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session; //This session has a new SessionID and hence does not have the data.

    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionName] != null)
    {
        // it never comes into this block
    }
}
```

During debug, I can see that the data is saved into the session as I can see the session name in the keys list.

The same code worked fine in another ASP.NET MVC project. I checked the `web.config` file of that project if there were any session related entries and there were none.

**UPDATE**: I have observed that, when saving the data the session id generated is different and when fetching the data, it has another id. I think this could be the reason, but why is it creating new session Ids when I'm not even refreshing the page. What can be done to fix this.

The `System.Web.Mvc` version is 5.2.3.0

Comment: Does your client allow cookies?

Comment: @CodeCaster. We are not using any cookies on site

Comment: You are. A session Id will be stored in a cookie, by default.

Comment: @CodeCaster.Okay. Could you pls suggest what can be done to keep the SessionID constant then

Comment: Check if your application restarts at every request for any reason, this thing happened to me when I include a library that unexpectedly saved logs in bin folder, because every change on bin folder restarts the application... every sessions fell down for being reinitialized with new Id after the application restart